# Story read 30 years back: Chalk (colored, I believe) that bring the object drawn to life

Tags: story-identification

Anyone have clues on what this story was ?
All I remember is reading this as a kid. It was an adventure story of kids who found colored chalk on a sidewalk and drew things on it and they came to life.

Wow, the smash up of colors that I visualized when reading that still is there. Can't remember the name of this story though.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: This sounds a lot like the TV show [*ChalkZone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChalkZone) dating from 1998...oh wait, that may lead to an answer!

Comment: This isn't it but there was an episode of Ultraman (Japan ~1975) that featured the chalk drawings of children coming to life as giant monsters.

Comment: ...was the chalk cursed?  the description's ringing a bell, but it would be a bit less innocent than "adventure for kids" makes it sound.

Comment: Did you read the story in a book, with or without illustrations, or seen it on TV? Please see our guide https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/4918 about how to ask a good story-identification question, as amflare recommended. You can also try to check TVTROPES WARNING http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArtInitiatesLife in case the story you're looking for is listed there.

Answer (score 7):

Was this [*Simon in the Land of Chalk Drawings*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_in_the_Land_of_Chalk_Drawings) by Edward McLachlan?

That was originally [a set of 4 books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0695880071), then later a UK television series also shown in the US.

[image: book cover for reference purposes]

Comment: "Well you know my name is Simon, and the things I draw come true. Oh the pictures take me, take me over, climb the ladder with you."

Comment: See also: *Harold and the Purple Crayon*